# D3 tree layout: weird behavior of shadow filter when .nodeSize() is applied

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

When I set [nodeSize](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#nodeSize) for the D3 tree layout, the applied shadow filter makes the lines invisible above certain point:
[image]

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/y9Ldey25/

Links will become visible again if no filter applied (in jsFiddle demo, comment out in css line 2: `filter: url(#shadow);`).

All works fine if I set total layout [size](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#size), and not nodeSize (swap commenting of lines 6 and 7).

Making svg height bigger makes the "visible area" bigger, but also creates too much unused space below, which is not appropriate. (swap commenting of lines 2 and 3).

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 2000
    //height = 4000;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .nodeSize([10, 100])
    //.size([height, width - 160])

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,400)")
    .append("g");
    
    // shadow filter
    var defs = svg.append("defs");
        var filter = defs
            .append("filter")
            .attr("id", "shadow")
            .attr("height", "130%")
            .attr("filterUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        filter.append("feOffset")
            .attr("in", "blur")
            .attr("dx", 4)
            .attr("dy", 4)
            .attr("result", "offsetBlur");
        filter.append("feFlood");
        filter.append("feComposite")
            .attr("operator", "in")
            .attr("in2", "offsetBlur");
        filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
            .attr("stdDeviation", 3);
        var merge = filter.append("feMerge");
        merge.append("feMergeNode");
        merge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

var json = data();

  var nodes = tree.nodes(json),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");


function data() {
return data = {"name":"flare","children":[{"name":"analytics","children":[{"name":"cluster","children":[{"name":"AgglomerativeCluster","size":3938},{"name":"CommunityStructure","size":3812},{"name":"HierarchicalCluster","size":6714},{"name":"MergeEdge","size":743}]},{"name":"graph","children":[{"name":"BetweennessCentrality","size":3534},{"name":"LinkDistance","size":5731},{"name":"MaxFlowMinCut","size":7840},{"name":"ShortestPaths","size":5914},{"name":"SpanningTree","size":3416}]},{"name":"optimization","children":[{"name":"AspectRatioBanker","size":7074}]}]},{"name":"animate","children":[{"name":"Easing","size":17010},{"name":"FunctionSequence","size":5842},{"name":"interpolate","children":[{"name":"ArrayInterpolator","size":1983},{"name":"ColorInterpolator","size":2047},{"name":"DateInterpolator","size":1375},{"name":"Interpolator","size":8746},{"name":"MatrixInterpolator","size":2202},{"name":"NumberInterpolator","size":1382},{"name":"ObjectInterpolator","size":1629},{"name":"PointInterpolator","size":1675},{"name":"RectangleInterpolator","size":2042}]},{"name":"ISchedulable","size":1041},{"name":"Parallel","size":5176},{"name":"Pause","size":449},{"name":"Scheduler","size":5593},{"name":"Sequence","size":5534},{"name":"Transition","size":9201},{"name":"Transitioner","size":19975},{"name":"TransitionEvent","size":1116},{"name":"Tween","size":6006}]},{"name":"data","children":[{"name":"converters","children":[{"name":"Converters","size":721},{"name":"DelimitedTextConverter","size":4294},{"name":"GraphMLConverter","size":9800},{"name":"IDataConverter","size":1314},{"name":"JSONConverter","size":2220}]},{"name":"DataField","size":1759},{"name":"DataSchema","size":2165},{"name":"DataSet","size":586},{"name":"DataSource","size":3331},{"name":"DataTable","size":772},{"name":"DataUtil","size":3322}]},{"name":"display","children":[{"name":"DirtySprite","size":8833},{"name":"LineSprite","size":1732},{"name":"RectSprite","size":3623},{"name":"TextSprite","size":10066}]},{"name":"flex","children":[{"name":"FlareVis","size":4116}]},{"name":"physics","children":[{"name":"DragForce","size":1082},{"name":"GravityForce","size":1336},{"name":"IForce","size":319},{"name":"NBodyForce","size":10498},{"name":"Particle","size":2822},{"name":"Simulation","size":9983},{"name":"Spring","size":2213},{"name":"SpringForce","size":1681}]},{"name":"query","children":[{"name":"AggregateExpression","size":1616},{"name":"And","size":1027},{"name":"Arithmetic","size":3891},{"name":"Average","size":891},{"name":"BinaryExpression","size":2893},{"name":"Comparison","size":5103},{"name":"CompositeExpression","size":3677},{"name":"Count","size":781},{"name":"DateUtil","size":4141},{"name":"Distinct","size":933},{"name":"Expression","size":5130},{"name":"ExpressionIterator","size":3617},{"name":"Fn","size":3240},{"name":"If","size":2732},{"name":"IsA","size":2039},{"name":"Literal","size":1214},{"name":"Match","size":3748},{"name":"Maximum","size":843},{"name":"methods","children":[{"name":"add","size":593},{"name":"and","size":330},{"name":"average","size":287},{"name":"count","size":277},{"name":"distinct","size":292},{"name":"div","size":595},{"name":"eq","size":594},{"name":"fn","size":460},{"name":"gt","size":603},{"name":"gte","size":625},{"name":"iff","size":748},{"name":"isa","size":461},{"name":"lt","size":597},{"name":"lte","size":619},{"name":"max","size":283},{"name":"min","size":283},{"name":"mod","size":591},{"name":"mul","size":603},{"name":"neq","size":599},{"name":"not","size":386},{"name":"or","size":323},{"name":"orderby","size":307},{"name":"range","size":772},{"name":"select","size":296},{"name":"stddev","size":363},{"name":"sub","size":600},{"name":"sum","size":280},{"name":"update","size":307},{"name":"variance","size":335},{"name":"where","size":299},{"name":"xor","size":354},{"name":"_","size":264}]},{"name":"Minimum","size":843},{"name":"Not","size":1554},{"name":"Or","size":970},{"name":"Query","size":13896},{"name":"Range","size":1594},{"name":"StringUtil","size":4130},{"name":"Sum","size":791},{"name":"Variable","size":1124},{"name":"Variance","size":1876},{"name":"Xor","size":1101}]},{"name":"scale","children":[{"name":"IScaleMap","size":2105},{"name":"LinearScale","size":1316},{"name":"LogScale","size":3151},{"name":"OrdinalScale","size":3770},{"name":"QuantileScale","size":2435},{"name":"QuantitativeScale","size":4839},{"name":"RootScale","size":1756},{"name":"Scale","size":4268},{"name":"ScaleType","size":1821},{"name":"TimeScale","size":5833}]},{"name":"util","children":[{"name":"Arrays","size":8258},{"name":"Colors","size":10001},{"name":"Dates","size":8217},{"name":"Displays","size":12555},{"name":"Filter","size":2324},{"name":"Geometry","size":10993},{"name":"heap","children":[{"name":"FibonacciHeap","size":9354},{"name":"HeapNode","size":1233}]},{"name":"IEvaluable","size":335},{"name":"IPredicate","size":383},{"name":"IValueProxy","size":874},{"name":"math","children":[{"name":"DenseMatrix","size":3165},{"name":"IMatrix","size":2815},{"name":"SparseMatrix","size":3366}]},{"name":"Maths","size":17705},{"name":"Orientation","size":1486},{"name":"palette","children":[{"name":"ColorPalette","size":6367},{"name":"Palette","size":1229},{"name":"ShapePalette","size":2059},{"name":"SizePalette","size":2291}]},{"name":"Property","size":5559},{"name":"Shapes","size":19118},{"name":"Sort","size":6887},{"name":"Stats","size":6557},{"name":"Strings","size":22026}]},{"name":"vis","children":[{"name":"axis","children":[{"name":"Axes","size":1302},{"name":"Axis","size":24593},{"name":"AxisGridLine","size":652},{"name":"AxisLabel","size":636},{"name":"CartesianAxes","size":6703}]},{"name":"controls","children":[{"name":"AnchorControl","size":2138},{"name":"ClickControl","size":3824},{"name":"Control","size":1353},{"name":"ControlList","size":4665},{"name":"DragControl","size":2649},{"name":"ExpandControl","size":2832},{"name":"HoverControl","size":4896},{"name":"IControl","size":763},{"name":"PanZoomControl","size":5222},{"name":"SelectionControl","size":7862},{"name":"TooltipControl","size":8435}]},{"name":"data","children":[{"name":"Data","size":20544},{"name":"DataList","size":19788},{"name":"DataSprite","size":10349},{"name":"EdgeSprite","size":3301},{"name":"NodeSprite","size":19382},{"name":"render","children":[{"name":"ArrowType","size":698},{"name":"EdgeRenderer","size":5569},{"name":"IRenderer","size":353},{"name":"ShapeRenderer","size":2247}]},{"name":"ScaleBinding","size":11275},{"name":"Tree","size":7147},{"name":"TreeBuilder","size":9930}]},{"name":"events","children":[{"name":"DataEvent","size":2313},{"name":"SelectionEvent","size":1880},{"name":"TooltipEvent","size":1701},{"name":"VisualizationEvent","size":1117}]},{"name":"legend","children":[{"name":"Legend","size":20859},{"name":"LegendItem","size":4614},{"name":"LegendRange","size":10530}]},{"name":"operator","children":[{"name":"distortion","children":[{"name":"BifocalDistortion","size":4461},{"name":"Distortion","size":6314},{"name":"FisheyeDistortion","size":3444}]},{"name":"encoder","children":[{"name":"ColorEncoder","size":3179},{"name":"Encoder","size":4060},{"name":"PropertyEncoder","size":4138},{"name":"ShapeEncoder","size":1690},{"name":"SizeEncoder","size":1830}]},{"name":"filter","children":[{"name":"FisheyeTreeFilter","size":5219},{"name":"GraphDistanceFilter","size":3165},{"name":"VisibilityFilter","size":3509}]},{"name":"IOperator","size":1286},{"name":"label","children":[{"name":"Labeler","size":9956},{"name":"RadialLabeler","size":3899},{"name":"StackedAreaLabeler","size":3202}]},{"name":"layout","children":[{"name":"AxisLayout","size":6725},{"name":"BundledEdgeRouter","size":3727},{"name":"CircleLayout","size":9317},{"name":"CirclePackingLayout","size":12003},{"name":"DendrogramLayout","size":4853},{"name":"ForceDirectedLayout","size":8411},{"name":"IcicleTreeLayout","size":4864},{"name":"IndentedTreeLayout","size":3174},{"name":"Layout","size":7881},{"name":"NodeLinkTreeLayout","size":12870},{"name":"PieLayout","size":2728},{"name":"RadialTreeLayout","size":12348},{"name":"RandomLayout","size":870},{"name":"StackedAreaLayout","size":9121},{"name":"TreeMapLayout","size":9191}]},{"name":"Operator","size":2490},{"name":"OperatorList","size":5248},{"name":"OperatorSequence","size":4190},{"name":"OperatorSwitch","size":2581},{"name":"SortOperator","size":2023}]},{"name":"Visualization","size":16540}]}]}
}
```

```css
path {
  filter: url(#shadow);
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Code taken from original example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify filterUnits in userSpace but then give a objectBoundingBox dimension. Change to:

```
    .attr("height", "130%")
    .attr("filterUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
```

Comment: thanx, it works here, but hides elements with no height (like straight lines). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284828/svg-adding-shadow-filter-makes-straight-line-invisible

Comment: The alternative is to switch to userSpaceOnUse and specify absolute dimensions e.g width="600" height="600". Or you can specify filters both ways and then switch between them with a javascript shim. (SVG won't let you do things like: 50% + 20px - at least not yet)

Comment: didn't manage to put your advice to action. still have top part 'cropped': https://jsfiddle.net/y9Ldey25/1/ (for straight line scroll to tree bottom. you'll see AxisLayout node.

Comment: well you also need to specify the x/y in your filter region.             .attr("y", "-900") seems to work ok. https://jsfiddle.net/be70x2c2/