# Adding feDropShadow to a vertical line in SVG makes it disappear

Tags: svg, svg-filters, dropshadow

I have the following SVG document:

```
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 21 484" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="0" stdDeviation="4"></feDropShadow>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="Artboard" stroke-width="5" stroke="#FF0000" fill="#000000" stroke-linecap="round">
    <path style="filter: url(#dropShadow)" d="M7.5,8.5 L7.5,471.5" id="path-1"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

In Firefox, when I open the SVG document, it simply shows a very thin (not 5 wide) vertical line. In Chrome, it doesn't show anything (nor does it in codepen, here: https://codepen.io/jwir3/pen/BJBqEK ).

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing incorrectly here, but it has something to do with the filter, because, if I remove the `filter: url(#dropShadow)` from the `path` definition, the line shows up as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG: adding shadow filter makes straight line invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284828/svg-adding-shadow-filter-makes-straight-line-invisible)

Comment: Just to add for search keywords: This also also affects `feMorphology` `dilate` and `erode`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use [objectBoundingBox units](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ObjectBoundingBox) if your shape has no height or width.

> Keyword objectBoundingBox should not be used when the geometry of the applicable element has no width or no height, such as the case of a horizontal or vertical line, even when the line has actual thickness when viewed due to having a non-zero stroke width since stroke width is ignored for bounding box calculations. When the geometry of the applicable element has no width or height and objectBoundingBox is specified, then the given effect (e.g., a gradient or a filter) will be ignored.

The default for filterUnits is objectBoundingBox units so you need to change that to userSpaceOnUse i.e.

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 21 484" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>Line Drop Shadow</title>
  <description>A red line with 5px width thickness and round caps, having a drop-shadow. This highlights the regression documented in PURP-1017.</description>
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="0" stdDeviation="4"></feDropShadow>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="Artboard" stroke-width="5" stroke="#FF0000" fill="#000000" stroke-linecap="round">
    <path style="filter: url(#dropShadow)" d="M7.5,8.5 L7.5,471.5" id="path-1"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

When processing filters, different browsers process in different `stroke`.
`Chrome` considers stroke as a value with a zero pixel, so it does not include it in the filter region.
Therefore, to make the result look the same in different browsers, it is better to replace `path` with `stroke-width="5"`, a rectangle with a width of 5px without `stroke` (`stroke="none"`)

In addition, the default values for the filter area are: `x = "- 10%"`, `y = "-10%"`, `width = "120%"`, `height = "120%"` - large blur sizes are usually truncated .

By default, [`filterUnits = "objectBoundingBox"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion) and therefore the values are specified in percentages.

To make it easier to calculate the size of the `filter region` action, specify the value of `filterUnits = "userSpaceOnUse"` and then you can specify all dimensions for the `filter region` in pixels.

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 21 484" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow" filterUnits = "userSpaceOnUse" x="4" y="0"  width="12" height="472">
      <feDropShadow dx="6" dy="4" stdDeviation="3"></feDropShadow>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="Artboard"  fill="#FF0000" filter="url(#dropShadow)" >
   <!-- <path style="filter: url(#dropShadow)" d="M7.5,8.5 L7.5,471.5" id="path-1" stroke-width="5" ></path>--> 
    <rect x="5" y="5" width="5" stroke="none" height="463"  /> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Swapping to `userSpaceOnUse` is the correct answer in most circumstances but has the following limitations:

1. The filter effects region will apply from -10% to 120% of the **canvas**, rather than the bounding box of the **element** (using more memory and processing time)
2. For large dynamic SVGs (such as created by d3) it can be hard to calculate the required filter x/y/width/height to ensure the filter applies to all elements.

An alternate (less elegant) solution is to apply the filter to a `<g>` and use a hidden node within this to give the group the correct width or height:

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow" width="20">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="0" stdDeviation="4"></feDropShadow>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="Artboard" style="filter: url(#dropShadow)">
    <circle r="5" cx="0" cy="0" visibility="hidden"></circle>
    <path d="M10,10 L10,100" stroke-width="5" stroke="#FF0000" fill="#000000" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```